production server can't pass npm run build
I made a nextjs 14.1.4 project on my local windows machine which I can build with npm run build without any problem, but
when I try to build on my production server: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with npm run build I get the following error:
./src/pages/about.tsx:7:20
Type error: Cannot find module '@/components/Layout' or its corresponding type declarations.

the code snippet from the component looks as:
import TestimonialPage from "@/components/about/TestimonialPage"
import Layout from "@/components/Layout"                    
import BaseButton from "@/components/base/BaseButton"

which is just a normal import statement.
I tried to change in my tsconfig.json the line with "moduleResolution": "bundler" with "moduleResolution": "node" but without any effect.
Also tried to change the "paths":
"paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }

to
"paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }

but without success.
What else can I do?

Try to access the machine and check its file system. Do you have the tsconfig.json file there? Is its content contain "paths": ...?

Yes, everything is there. Checked it, also changed the "paths" values multiple times on the production server :/.

Make sure to (double) check for casing on the file names. Is it Layout or layout ?

On my local machine, I changed the layout name to Layout and committed the changes. Then on the production server, I pulled everything but there I never checked, if the file had its name changed. It didn't. On the production server, the file was still named layout.tsx. So @JeppeHasseriis, thanks for the hint! :-)

Good to hear! Happy to help! :)

@JeppeHasseriis thanks.
And if you would post an answer, then I will gladly accept :-)

Some OS's are case-sensitive when importing files. Make sure to double-check if the right path is
import Layout from "@/components/Layout" // capital letter

or
import Layout from "@/components/layout" // lower case


Verify that your tsconfig.json file is correctly configured to handle module resolution
{
   "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "@/*": ["src/*"]
        }
      }
    }


unfortunately, it didn't help.
